# Align footer at the bottom of the content, push to right of the sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to place the footer at the bottom of the content, but not spread across the whole width of the page. The footer should always be bottom if the content is not place i.e. as shown in figure 1. The sidebar can be toggled by the button place at the `navbar`.

[image]

I was only able to get as shown below:

[image]

The sidebar should push the footer to the right, but it is always at the top. As, when the sidebar is hidden or collapsed the footer should occupy the width of the page as occupied buy the content.

HTML implementation is in the following structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <!-- Navbar -->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      </div>
   </nav>
   <!-- Sidebar -->
   <div id="sidebar" class="shadow-sm"></div>
   <!-- Page Content -->
   <div id="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h1>
                  Collapsing Menu
                  <small class="text-muted">Version 2.1</small>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<footer id="page-footer" class="py-3 bg-dark text-light">
   <div class="container">

   </div>
</footer>
```

CSS for the footer and sidebar:

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
    margin-top: 54px;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 55px);
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: right .5s ease,left .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: right .5s ease,left .5s ease;
    -o-transition: right .5s ease,left .5s ease;
    transition: right .5s ease,left .5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend putting the footer in the div with the id "content," or the one with class "container-fluid."

See how that works.

Long Version: Your footer is currently being spaced according to its parent context. In the current version, the context that you're placing your footer in is not in the scope of what you posted- this means that, in terms of processing, the footer is not aware of the content container. The quickest solution here would be to place the footer in the context of the container that holds your content. This way, the footer is contained by the same div that the content is presented in. Whether or not it touches the bottom of the screen is up to your css.

Hope that helps.

Comment: there is no difference in putting the footer either inside the `content` div or inside the `container-fluid` div. There is the same result on both case i.e. as shown in image 2

Comment: I agree, the footer should be inside the content div @User_4373

Comment: @Zim in my present context i got no difference while placing the footer inside the content div.

Comment: yes because it's position:fixed and it's removed from the normal DOM flow. it shouldn't be fixed. you should force the height of container-fluid and the footer will be pushed to the bottom

Comment: @Zim you were right! I moved the footer to `content` div, and removed the `position:fixed`. But when their is no content the footer moved `up` with the content. their isn't the way to stick the footer to the bottom of the page when there is no content.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var wheight= $(window).height();
  var contentheight=$(".content").height();
  if(wheight>contentheight){
    $("footer").addClass("fixedfooter");
  }
  else{
     $("footer").removeClass("fixedfooter");
}
})
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.sidebar {
   height: 100vh;
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  background:red;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.page{
  width:80%;
  float:left;
  
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
}
footer {
  width:calc(100%);
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.fixedfooter{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:calc(100% - 20%)!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="content">my content</div>
    <footer>my footer </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is it with jquery! applying a class with fixed position to the footer when the content height is not higher then windows height!
try changing height of content to check result!

Comment: their isn't any alternative for `jquery`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidebar {
   height: 100vh;
  width:20%;
  background:red;
}
.wrapper{
  display:flex;

}
.page{
  width:80%;
    display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:;
  
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
}
footer {
  width:calc(100%);
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="content">my content</div>
    <footer>my footer </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is another method with only css!

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by using this code from w3schools.com

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```